# immutable JS with Typescript: "No overload matches this call" when creating Map / OrderedMap

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I am using Typescript version `3.8.3` with `immutable@4.0.0-rc.12`.

When I create `OrderedMap` using two-dimensional array to instantiate it, I get error from Typescript.

```
let v: OrderedMap<number, string> = OrderedMap([ [ 3, '2' ] ])
```

[Example on Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-immutable-js-instantiation-n1559?file=/src/index.ts)

Seems like definition file for library could be wrong? (`immutable-nonambient.d.ts(1421, 39)`). This is the error it gives me:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(collection: Iterable<[string | number, string | number]>): OrderedMap<string | number, string | number>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<[string | number, string | number]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<(string | number)[], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<[string | number, string | number], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<(string | number)[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<[string | number, string | number], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<(string | number)[]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<[string | number, string | number]>'.
              Type '(string | number)[]' is missing the following properties from type '[string | number, string | number]': 0, 1
  Overload 2 of 4, '(obj: { [key: string]: string; }): OrderedMap<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
immutable-nonambient.d.ts(1421, 39): The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

I get the same thing for `Map`. If I create empty `Map` or `OrderedMap` and assign it to variable, I can perform operations on the data without error so it has trouble with initializing this way.

Instantiating using this signature: `OrderedMap({ 3: '2' })` works without compilation error. But obviously I can't use it since I want my keys to be numbers and using the array notation is the only way to achieve it.

Comment: Could you provide more info about your code, or maybe an stackblitz?

Comment: I edited my question to provide example and I also tried it without `@types/immutable` definitions, I still get the compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `@types/immutable` [is no longer supported](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/immutable)

> This package has been deprecated
>
> Author message:
>
> This is a stub types definition for Facebook's Immutable (https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js). Facebook's Immutable provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/immutable installed!

After removing it, you should get nice type hints in your editor.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vwetmv?file=index.ts

**Update**

Adding `"target": "es2015"` in compiler options removes the error.

See docs: [Using TypeScript with Immutable.js v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable#using-typescript-with-immutablejs-v4)

> Immutable.js type definitions embrace ES2015. While Immutable.js itself supports legacy browsers and environments, its type definitions require TypeScript's 2015 lib. Include either `"target": "es2015"` or `"lib": "es2015"` in your `tsconfig.json`, or provide `--target es2015` or `--lib es2015` to the `tsc` command.

Comment: I'm not sure how stackblitz is set up but I created code sandbox and I get the same error as locally: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-immutable-js-instantiation-n1559

Comment: I added `"target": "es2015",` to your example (in tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions) and it removed the error